# Php-fpm doesn't start after some changes

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm

I'm using php-fpm 7.3 with apache on the centos 7.

I installed php and apache with directamin control panel on my server before.

I added these below configs in to the global section of php fpm in `/usr/local/php73/etc/php-fpm.conf` directory.

```
emergency_restart_threshold 10
emergency_restart_interval 1m
process_control_timeout 10s
```

After I add these above configs to `php-fpm`, it doesn't start.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is just that you typed it out rather than copy/ paste ... but the syntax uses `=` i.e.

```
[global]
emergency_restart_threshold = 10
emergency_restart_interval = 1m
process_control_timeout = 10s
```

I don't see anything wrong with it otherwise?  Just make sure that it's definitely set as a global directive and not for a pool.

Comment: Thank you, I added `=` and problem solved.